# How can I submit a html form post that has several different iterated values?

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

This is a Spring MVC project.

So the following JSP

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
   <table>  
     <c:forEach items="${nameList}" var="studentList">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${studentList.name}"/> ${studentList.regNo}</td>
        </tr>
     </c:forEach>
   </table>
```

returns values like

```
Ramu
Somu
Mamu
Komu
```

I want to make each value as a post url, so that, if the user clicks any one link, I would like to submit as like the following jsp code does

```
<form method="post" action="number" id="number">
            <div style="text-align: center;" >                
                             <input  width="20" type="text" data-validation="numbers" id="regNo" name="regNo" size="30" maxLength="50" placeholder="Enter Register Number">                     
            </div>                      
    </form>
```

I don't wanna do GET.
 How can I do this? Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this
  `<td><a href='www.xyz.com:port/number?regNo=${studentList.regNo}><c:out value="${studentList.name}"/> </a></td>`

And `regNo` you can get as the `request` parameter in controller
 or 
**`Path parameter`** in your controller like

```
<td><a href='www.xyz.com:port/number/${studentList.regNo}><c:out value="${studentList.name}"/> </a></td>
```

And modify your controller's configuration accordingly.

Comment: Is it possible to do as a POST request?

Comment: Is there any alternative way instead of typing "www.xyz.com:port/number"?

Comment: Yes there is alternative  `<a href='number?regNo=${studentList.regNo}>`

Comment: Does changing the href attribute value from <a href='www.xyz.com:port/number?regNo=${studentList.regNo}>  to <a href="www.xyz.com:port/number?regNo=<c:out value="${studentList.regNo}"/>">  is good? Which one is better and why?

Comment: No it's not c:out is uded to display the value.

Comment: No. Even if I use c:out its working. But I would like to know does it add any advantage?

Comment: No it will not add any advantage. If you look closely you are achieving the same thing, then why do add some extra words in codes.

Comment: Could you answer this question?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26352959/how-can-i-filter-the-result-given-by-cfor-each-using-the-value-selected-in-a-dr